# Flutter WebViewPlus | "Unsupported operation: ServerSocket.bind" error

Tags: flutter, dart, webview, serversocket

I want to display a local html file within my Flutter app. Therefore I decided to use the "webview_flutter_plus" package which is an extension of the "webview_flutter" package. Unfortunately, I couldn't even run the project with very basic code since I always encountered following error: "Unsupported operation: ServerSocket.bind". Let me explain, what I tried to do:

First, I replaced the lib/main.dart code with the example code from [pub.dev webview_flutter_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter_plus/example). Then I added my own example HTML file ("content.html", which is located in a directory "files" in root) to the pubspec.yaml by adding "- files/". In lib/main.dart (line 47, initialurl) I replaced the referenced HTML file with "files/content.html" which references my own file. I attached all the relevant code below.

Then, I tried to run the app for Chrome. Unfortunately, the WebView doesn't load and there is an error thrown: "Unsupported operation: ServerSocket.bind". The error message looks like this:

[ServerSocket.bind error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAZXA.png)

Is anyone familiar with the WebViewPlus package or this error - or probably both? I can't really figure out how to continue, since I already tried the simplest version by using the example code.

lib/main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter_plus/webview_flutter_plus.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const WebViewPlusExample());
}

class WebViewPlusExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const WebViewPlusExample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: WebViewPlusExampleMainPage(),
    );
  }
}

class WebViewPlusExampleMainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const WebViewPlusExampleMainPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _WebViewPlusExampleMainPageState createState() =>
      _WebViewPlusExampleMainPageState();
}

class _WebViewPlusExampleMainPageState
    extends State<WebViewPlusExampleMainPage> {
  WebViewPlusController? _controller;
  double _height = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('webview_flutter_plus Example'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Text("Height of WebviewPlus: $_height",
              style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          SizedBox(
            height: _height,
            child: WebViewPlus(
              serverPort: 5353,
              javascriptChannels: null,
              initialUrl: 'files/content.html',
              onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                _controller = controller;
              },
              onPageFinished: (url) {
                _controller?.getHeight().then((double height) {
                  debugPrint("Height: " + height.toString());
                  setState(() {
                    _height = height;
                  });
                });
              },
              javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

files/content.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Test </title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1> Test </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```